# steps for creating  UIScrollView with Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm in the midst of trying to use a UIScrollView and there appears to be some fundamental thing that I'm just not understanding.

Let's say I want to use a UIScrollView in my iphone app.  I have a View filled with buttons that is 320x700.  Obviously, this is too big for the iPhone which is 320x480.  So I know I have to use a UIScrollView.  However, is this the order that I should be creating the objects

1. Create a UIScrollView that is 320x700 as the dimensions in "View"
2. Place all my buttons, etc, on this scroll view
3. In the viewDidLoad set the contentSize to 320x700
4. Set the delegate of the UIScrollView to the File Owner, and the view of the FileOwner to the UIScrollView
5. Reset the size of the View back to 320x480.

Is this right?

This works, but it doesn't make sense to me.  I get that the View is supposed to be the canvas, where I add all the UI elements.  I want the "canvas" of the iPhone app to be 320x700, and I want to be able to put my buttons, etc on this 320x700 canvas.  But if I don't change the size of the UIScrollView back to 320x480, it won't scroll, because I need to set the content size of the UIScrollView larger than its size.

But if I set the size of the UIScrollView to 320x480, then I don't see the screen and the buttons between 480 and 700 in Interface Builder!  So it seems like I'm supposed to make all my edits and add all my UI elements to the UIScrollView, and then set it back to the 320x480!

Is there some other way to do this that makes more sense?  What am I missing in my understanding of how this should work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### UPDATE

I have posted [another solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889377/77567) which I think is simpler and better.

#### ORIGINAL

Here's another way to do this that you might like better:

1. Set the File's Owner placeholder's custom class to your view controller subclass.
2. Create the `UIScrollView` as a top-level object in your nib.  Set its size to the screen size (320x460) or just turn on a status bar under "Simulated Metrics".
3. Connect the scroll view's `delegate` outlet to File's Owner.
4. Set the File's Owner's `view` outlet to the scroll view.
5. Create a `UIView` as **another** top-level object in your nib.  This will be your content view.
6. Set the content view's size to 320x700.
7. Create a strong (or retain, if not using ARC) outlet named `contentView` in your view controller (File's Owner) and connect it to the content view.
8. Put your buttons in the content view.
9. In your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, do this:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self.view addSubview:self.contentView];
       ((UIScrollView *)self.view).contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
   }
   ```
10. In your view controller's `viewDidUnload`, do this:

    ```
    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        self.contentView = nil;
        [super viewDidUnload];
    }
    ```

[image: scrollbuttons project window]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmwXG.png)

Comment: Thank you!  This makes more sense to me... do the "stitching" of the views at run time, so that the building of the content views isn't interfered with by Interface Builder.  One question, why set the scroll view size to 460?  Is that so that it fulfills the requirement that the scroll view has to be smaller than the 480?

Comment: The status bar takes 20 points.  The size doesn't really matter much, because `UIViewController` should resize it to be full-screen anyway.

Comment: For scrollview, Interface builder has wasted hours and hours of my time.  It would have been faster to build it in code myself. Most of the time it's my fault, but in this case IB has some issues with throwing everything off by the height of a uinavigation bar. I'm confident that I'm doing it right.  I like the stitching things up with code.

Comment: Why is it necessary to set contentView to nil in viewDidUnload?

Comment: If your `contentView` outlet is strong, it will keep the view in memory unless you set it to nil.

Answer (score 5):

You are right, the View is the canvas where you add all the UI elements.
Interface builder is kind of weird at first but you will get used to it, that is just the way it works.

You are getting stuck on the fact that you have to resize the ScrollView. You should think of it like this:
The ScrollView has a frame size and a content size. The way it's built is that if the content size is larger than the frame size then it will scroll. You have to make the frame as big as you need to in the interface builder so you can position the elements that go inside. When you run the application you should resize the frame of the scroll to fit inside the iPhone's screen resolution. It doesn't make sense for your controls to have a frame bigger than the screen.

```
--------------------------------------------
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |<------------------ iPhone Screen frame
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |<------- ScrollView Content size
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |<----------------- ScrollView Frame Size
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |      
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         |                      |         |
|         ------------------------         |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
--------------------------------------------
```

I hope this representation will make it clearer how things should suppose to work.To put it some other way, the scroll frame is the hole trough you can see the content, if the whole is as big as the content then you have no need to scroll cos you can see it all.

I would suggest also trying to write the components in code without using IB to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense as well.  I think you're right about getting stuck on the difference between the frame and the content size.  Resizing at runtime makes sense as well I will try that out!