# UIScrollView doesn't respond to scrollRectToVisible:animated: called from ViewDidLoad in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

The main view (the one shown at launch) for my application is an UIScrollView that contains an UIView. To organize my nibs I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118796/steps-for-creating-uiscrollview-with-interface-builder/9119126#9119126) method and everything works fine.

However, when calling `scrollRectToVisible:animated` in `ViewDidLoad` in the main view controller (having already set the scrollView's content size) the scrollView doesn't scroll to the indicated CGRect.

There are two strange factors to consider:

1. The scrollView scrolls as expected on iOS 6 (the problem exposed presents itself on iOS 5).
2. If I call the code to scroll with a 2 sec delay the scroll happens.

Comment: It may be better to do your scrolling in ``viewWillAppear:animated:``

Answer (score 1):

Call the scrollRectToVisible:animated in the viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated.

I solved the same problem with this.

Comment: Surely that would cause a visible animated scroll / jump. What if you just wanted 'scrollRectToVisible:animated' to adjust the `scrollOffset` before `viewDidAppear:`?